# Detecting unresolved symbols in an ELF executable

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld, elf

Let's say I have two files:

```
// shared.c (will be compiled to 'shared.so')
#include <stdio.h>
int f() { printf("hello\n"); }
```

and

```
// exe.c (will be compiled to 'exe')
#include <stdio.h>
int f();
int main() { 
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 5) f(); 
}
```

I compile both files as following:

```
gcc -shared shared.c -o libshared.so
gcc exe.c -o exe -lshared -L.
```

When I run `exe` and type 5, it will call f and then exit. However, if I delete `f` from `shared.c` and recompile it I will get a runtime symbol lookup error only if I type 5. Is there a way that I can check that `exe` has all its symbols that will work independent of user input in this case? Preferrably without running it.

Comment: Yes, I think you can. Have a look at how `nm` and `objdump` programs work and how they use the elf table to see where each symbol is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ldd -r exe` command to list the shared library dependencies.
Here is my output for your example without the `f` function:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd -r ./exe
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcfa7c3000)
        libshared.so => ./libshared.so (0x00007f303a02e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e26c00000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e26400000)
undefined symbol: f     (./exe)
```

(Don't mind the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` part. It is used to tell to look for shared libraries in the current directory)

Comment: Sorry @Eugene I accidentally hit the downvote an didn't realise until too late and can't change it now unless you edit your answer. Let me know if you do and I'll change my vote.

Answer (score 0):

@tohava
When you compile the executable and link it with the shared object, ld (linker) checks if all referenced symbols are available in the list of shared objects your executable is dependent on and will throw an error if any symbol was unresolved.

So, I am not sure how you managed to get a runtime error when you removed f() from the shared library and rebuilt the executable. (I did the exercise myself and got the linker error).

Comment: I did not rebuild the executable, only the shared objects

Comment: Ah. But why would you not build the executable when an associated library has changed?Anyway, if the binary is not your concern (I mean, if you are only the library provider), then, like Eugene Sh. already mentioned, ldd will do the job.

Comment: Why should I rebuild the executable if a library changes? I should only rebuild the executable if one of its sources changes (In the case of a library change, this will be a header file common to it and the library).